# Replacing Month Name with its respective Month Number

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

I am trying to replace a month value in a `<month>` tag to its respective month number for example : `<month>Feb</month>` should be replace with `<month>02</month>`

I have tried this,

```
Dim strFile As String = File.ReadAllText(TextBox1.Text & "\" & parentFolder & ".xml")
    strFile = Regex.Replace(strFile, "<conf-start.*?><day>(.*?)</day><month>Feb</month>", "$&<month>02</month>")
    File.WriteAllText(TextBox1.Text & "\" & parentFolder & ".xml", strFile)
```

But it is giving me the below output

```
<conf-start iso-8601-date="0"><day>00</day><month>Feb</month><month>02</month>
```

Instead its adding tag next to month name the output i wanted is as follows,

```
<conf-start iso-8601-date="0"><day>00</day><month>02</month>
```

Month name should be replaced with its respective number.
Thanks in advance..

Comment: Don't use regex to deal with XML/HTML...

Comment: Could it be you're asking the same question twice? Please revise one question and close/delete the other.

Answer (score 0):

Use XDocument it's easy to figure out.  Then just parse the node contents with either

DateTime dateTime = DateTime.ParseExact("November", "MMMM", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
DateTime dateTime = DateTime.ParseExact("Nov", "MMM", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);

depending on the format of the month.  That'll give you a date like 11/1/2014 12:00:00 AM.  I was a little surprised the year is current and not the epoch but we don't care.

Then 
dateTime.Month.ToString() to replace the node content.

The DateTime trick doesn't like "." on abbreviated months in the second case but you sample doesn't contain that.  If it comes up use dateString = dateString.TrimEnd('.') to get rid of the "."